# Updating filtered replicated rows on subscriber fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a merge replication scenario with 1 distributor/publisher and many subscribers.
There are only a few articles which are unfiltered everything else is filtered by HOST_NAME() and thus creating distinct (nonoverlapping) partitions.
I also tried filtering via SUSER_NAME() to no avail.

Filtering and distribution work perfect but updating on the subscriber fails with this error message:

> Cannot update the column in article '%s'. 
>   The article has a value of 2 or 3 (nonoverlapping partitions) 
>   for the partition_options property, and the column is involved
>   in a row filter and/or a join filter. In this situation, the column cannot be
>   updated at a Subscriber or republisher; it must be updated at the top-level Publisher

The article it fails on has a partition_options-setting of "Nonoverlapping, single subscription". 
The SQL I tried to execute is a simple parameterized UPDATE of a few nvarchars and bits.

Anybody any Idea what I'm missing? It can't be far...

EDIT:
SQL Server 2008 R2 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

The Problem was that the update I tried to do (well Entity Framework in this case) was also including the column I used in the filter expression, so this update would change the partition of this dataset which is apparently not allowed.